# Weakened jacobian conjecture for entire functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, several-complex-variables, jacobian-conjecture

A rudin's theorem is the assertion that any polynomial injection between affine spaces of the same dimension has a polynomial inverse, and the inverse is also given by polynomials.
The jacobian conjecture gets reduced to asking injectivity of the polynomial map from the rudin’s theorem if the jacobian is a nonzero constant.

I am asking if the same holds if polynomials are replaced by holomorphic. Replace polynomials with holomorphic functions, and instead of asking for invertibility ask just injectivity of the holomorphic map if the jacobian does not vanish or is a non-zero constant. Due to the existence of fatou-bieberbach domains injectivity won't imply surjectivity in case of holomorphic functions unlike the case of polynomial.

- link for rudin's theorem: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/infinite-fields-finite-fields-and-the-ax-grothendieck-theorem/
- link for jacobian conjecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture
- link for fatou-bieberbach domain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%E2%80%93Bieberbach_domain

Comment: Is Rudin's theorem the assertion that any polynomial injection between affine spaces of the same dimension has a polynomial inverse?

Comment: yes that's the rudin's theorem i am saying.sorry i am adding the statement in my question

Comment: Doesn't the exponential map give a counter-example to the assertion right away?

Comment: what's it's jacobian.i don't think it's a nonzero constant

Comment: As noted in http://www.ohio.edu/people/lopez/center/formanek1.pdf, $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (e^{z_1},e^{-z_1}z_2)$ gives a counterexample with constant Jacobian.